# java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method f.l.e.k, parameter $this$toList at f.l.e.k(Unknown Source:2)

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I have an app it works well on my phone and when I install it manually, but in play store I'm getting this error, please help

FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.theecoder.arkwork, PID: 17630
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method f.l.e.k, parameter $this$toList

```
at f.l.e.k(Unknown Source:2)
at d.d.a.d.b.h.a(:15)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.b(Unknown Source:29)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.c(Unknown Source:44)
at c.o.o.i(:1)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$a.run(Unknown Source:18)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: The stack trace is not too meaningful as your App has been obfuscated.
Have you installed the release build manually on your phone?

Comment: yes, when I install it manually it works perfectly with no errors, but in production it is crushing

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the reason I got a crush in production is that I used "minifyEnabled true" and I did not add the okhttp proguard rules.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should always test the release build before you push it to production (as in, switch to the ``release`` build variant and ``Run`` that on your devices/emulators)